# Use wpf image control to show an image from filesystem

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-controls

I want to show an image from a file using an wpf image control. The image file resides in the application directory.

```
<Image Stretch="Fill" Source="dashboard.jpg" />
```

The file `dashboard.jpg` should be replaceable during or after deployment. How do I have to add the image to the project and what BuildAction do I have to use to have the image read from the file system rather than any source I cannot change after deployment. What source uri do I have to use?

Answer (score 35):

```
ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\FileName.gif"));    
image1.Source = imageSource;
```

Answer (score 24):

In markup:

```
<Image Stretch="Fill">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="dashboard.jpg"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```